# python olap.xmla mdx queries returning single value?

Tags: python, olap, xmla, iccube

I am always getting a single value in MDX query using python. I am connecting to icCube which has xmla support.

```
provider = xmla.XMLAProvider()
con = provider.connect(location='conn_str',username='q1',password='q2')
cmd="""WITH MEMBER Measures.[Avg Profit Margin] AS Sum(SOMETHING,    Measures.[Profit Margin]) select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Profit Margin]} ON columns, {[Client Country]} ON rows FROM [XYZ]"""

res=con.Execute(cmd,Catalog="cube_closed_contracts")
print res.getSlice()
```

why does it always return a single value?

```
[[(Cell){
     _CellOrdinal = "0"
     Value = 0.0358054
     FmtValue = "3.58%"
   }]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the MDX query is expected to return more than one cell ?

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[Avg Profit Margin] AS ... 
select 
      NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Profit Margin]} ON columns, 
      {[Client Country]} ON rows 
FROM [XYZ]
```

" [Client Country] on rows " means the default member of [Client Country] so I believe this will return a single cell result. I would try the request in the icCube MDX editor.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to modify the query and test in MDX editor. I still don't know why the python xmla package doesn't return column names from res object. Inside iccube i can type in the mdx query and get a nicely formatted table with column names etc. In the python interface it's just values.